# why does the title of the plot keep repeating?

Tags: matlab, plot, fft

Why does MATLAB keep repeating the title? Here is a screen shot:

[image]

It should have stopped after Freq, but it repeats the whole thing again.

This is the code I am using for display:

```
I1_amp = max(I1_FFT);
I1_RMS = I1_amp/sqrt(2);
I1_freq = find(I1_FFT==I1_amp)-1; % -1 because in matlab the index starts from 1

subplot 511
plot(axis,I1_FFT);
title(sprintf(' 1st harmonic => Ipeak = %.2f , Irms = %.2f , Freq = %i',I1_amp,I1_RMS,I1_freq));
```

Comment: Use the `'first'` (or `'last'`) option with `find` if you don't want to be caught out when it returns more than one index.

Comment: omg such a silly mistake. Its fixed now. Would you like to put that as an answer? that way i can accept this as an answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sprintf` and friends are vectorised, so if there are leftover elements in the data it will keep repeating the format string until it has consumed as much as it can. That's the "why".

Presumably in this case the maximum value isn't unique, so `find` has returned more than one index. If you don't need to handle this specially and just want the first or last appearance, you can pass the appropriate option to `find`:

```
I1_freq = find(I1_FFT==I1_amp, 'last')-1;
```

If the first index is sufficient, in most cases you can skip `find` altogether since `max` has that already:

```
[I1_amp I1_freq] = max(I1_FFT);  % assuming I1_FFT is a vector
```

Note that `find` returns linear indices whereas `max` operates over a given dimension, so for matrices you'd need to linearise them with `(:)` to get the equivalent of `find(...,'first')`, rather than a vector of per-column/row indices.